# Infinite-dimensional inner product spaces: if $A$ is a skew operator, does it follow that $A-I$ is invertible?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, operator-theory, inner-products, adjoint-operators

I am trying to find an answer to this question: if $A$ is a skew-Hermitian operator (i.e., $A^* = -A$) on an infinite-dimensional inner product space, does it follow that $A-I$ is invertible? The question appears as exercise 7(a) after S.74 on page 145 of PR Halmos's "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces" - Second Edition.

So far, I have managed to establish the result in the finite-dimensional inner product spaces alone. Proof: if $(A-I)x = 0$ for any vector $x$, then $Ax = x$. Thus, we have the inner product $(x, x) = (Ax, x) = (x, A^*x) = (x, -Ax) = (x, -x) = -(x, x) \implies (x, x) = 0$. It follows that $x = 0$ due to the inner product property. In summary, $(A-I)x = 0 \implies x = 0$, and therefore $A-I$ is invertible (since the space is finite-dimensional).

Haven't been able to prove the assertion in infinite-dimensional inner product spaces. Would appreciate a guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't this work for the infinite dimensional case? Isn't it still the case that if $B x = 0 \implies x = 0$ for some operator $B$ in an inner product space, then the map $B$ is invertible?

Comment: I am not aware if the invertibility result extends to infinite-dimensional spaces too. I have followed PR Halmos's "Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces". Theorem 2 from S.36 (page 62) of the book states that "$A$ is invertible on a finite-dimensional vector space if and only if $Ax = 0 \implies x = 0$" with a proof. The book does not say that this result extends to infinite-dimensional spaces too.

Comment: Indeed, it is false in general. An operator may be injective but not invertible, e.g. the shift $$(x_1,x_2, \ldots) \mapsto (0,x_1,x_2, \ldots)$$
on $\ell^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your space is complete (that is, a Hilbert space), the answer is yes. On a Hilbert space, the spectrum of a selfadjoint operator is real. As $iA$ is selfadjoint, ou have $\sigma(A)\subset i\mathbb R$, so $$\sigma(A-I)=\{-1+\lambda:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A)\}\subset -1+i\mathbb R,$$ so $0\not\in\sigma(A)$.

In general, the answer is no. Let $V=\mathbb C[x]$ with $\langle f,g\rangle=\int_0^1f(t)\,\overline{g(t)}\,dt$. Let $A$ be $(Af)(t)=i\,t^2\,f(t)$. We have $$\langle A^*f,g\rangle=\langle f,Ag\rangle=\int_0^1f(t)\,\overline{it^2g(t)}\,dt=\langle-Af,g\rangle.
$$
So $A^*=-A$. But $A-I$ is multiplication by $it^2-1$, which is not surjective.

Comment: Thanks for a comprehensive response! Really convincing :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that $H$ is a Hilbert space. For $x \in H$ we have $\langle Ax,x\rangle = -\langle x,Ax\rangle$ so
$$\|(A-I)x\|^2 = \|Ax-x\|^2 = \langle Ax,x\rangle - \langle Ax,x\rangle - \langle x,Ax\rangle + \langle x,x\rangle = \|Ax\|^2 + \|x\|^2 \ge \|x\|^2.$$
Therefore, $A-I$ is bounded from below so in particular $A-I$ is injective and its range $R(A-I)$ is closed. Since $A-I$ is normal, we have
$$H = N(A-I) \oplus \overline{R(A-I)} = R(A-I)$$
so $A-I$ is surjective. We conclude that $A-I$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks! That's enlightening. However, I am afraid that the original problem from PR Halmos's book does not talk about Hilbert Spaces. In fact, the book introduces Hilbert Spaces much later. So, unfortunately, the question remains unaddressed to an extent.